# How to spring inject configuration value for Joda Period

Tags: spring, configuration, jodatime, period

How can I use the @Value annotation to configure a Joda-Time *Period* field in my spring bean?

E.g. Given the following component class:

```
@Component
public class MyService {

  @Value("${myapp.period:P1D}")
  private Period periodField;
...
}
```

I want to use standard ISO8601 format to define the period in a properties file.

I get this error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type [java.lang.String] to required type [org.joda.time.Period]: no matching editors or conversion strategy found
    at org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterDelegate.convertIfNecessary(TypeConverterDelegate.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterDelegate.convertIfNecessary(TypeConverterDelegate.java:125)
    at org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterSupport.doConvert(TypeConverterSupport.java:61)
    ... 35 more
```

Comment: It is likely that you need to register a converter String->JodaPeriod

Comment: Thanks. Do you know of any examples for this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you can do is [register a Spring `ConversionService`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/validation.html#core-convert) bean and [implement a proper converter](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/validation.html#core-convert-Spring-config).

```
@Bean
public ConversionServiceFactoryBean conversionService() {
    ConversionServiceFactoryBean conversionServiceFactoryBean = new ConversionServiceFactoryBean();
    Set<Converter<?, ?>> myConverters = new HashSet<>();
    myConverters.add(new StringToPeriodConverter());
    conversionServiceFactoryBean.setConverters(myConverters);
    return conversionServiceFactoryBean;
}

public class StringToPeriodConverter implements Converter<String, Period> {

    @Override
    public Period convert(String source) {
        return Period.parse(source);
    }
}
```

Comment: Great stuff. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 8):

A simple solution that does not require any java code is to use [Spring Expression Language (SpEL)](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/expressions.html).

(My example uses java.time.Duration and not Joda stuff but I think you get it anyway.)

```
    @Value("#{T(java.time.Duration).parse('${notifications.maxJobAge}')}")
    private Duration maxJobAge;
```

Comment: Great answer! Thank you.

Comment: this requires a lot of tinkering if I must have a default value of `null`, since java.time.Duration::parse will be unhappy about `null` argument.

Answer (score 1):

Another, not elegant, option, is to use a String setter who invokes the parse method.

```
@Value("${myapp.period:P1D}")
public void setPeriodField(String periodField)
{
    if (isBlank(periodField))
        this.periodField= null;
    this.periodField= Duration.parse(periodField);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For joda-time:2.10.13 and spring-boot:2.3.2.RELEASE next example (like in question) is worked:

```
  @Value("${myapp.period:P1D}")
  private Period periodField;
```

If you use java.time.Period, in addition, worked a simple period property format (org.springframework.boot.convert.PeriodStyle):

```
  @Value("${myapp.period:1d}")
  private Period periodField;
```